# "Price from" in configurable products

Tags: magento-1.9

I’m trying to display « price from » for configurable products if its attribute(s) have a price (I also have configurable products where associated products have all the same price and where I don’t need to display this text).

I guess I have to modify templates\catalog\product/price.phtml but didn’t managed to find where I should code it and how to do it. I’m new to Magento and not very comfortable with coding yet, but would like to avoid the use of extension.

I tried to check with this solution: http://dltr.org/blog/magento/254/Magento-show-FROM-price-on-configurable-products but it’s related to EE… and I’m running on CE 1.9.3.1 version with RWD theme.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Forward